# Reading array values in PHP and assigning to individual string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array which gives this result:

```
Array
(
  [count] => 1
  [0] => Array
  (
    [sn] => Array
    (
      [count] => 1
      [0] => Smith
    )
    [0] => sn
    [givenname] => Array
    (
      [count] => 1
      [0] => John
    )
    [1] => givenname
    [mail] => Array
    (
      [count] => 1
      [0] => john.smith@mydomain.com
    )
    [2] => mail
    [count] => 3
    [dn] => CN=John Smith,OU=IT Admin,DC=mylocaldomain,DC=local
  )
)
```

How do I go about extracting the Email address from this array result into a single string?
I need to able to reference the Email address, but can't find a way to pull that information out.

The meat of the LDAP code is along the lines of:

```
$dn = “OU=IT Admin,DC=mylocaldomain,DC=local”;
$ds = $ldapconnectionstring;
$person = “johnsmith”;
$filter="(|(sn=$person*)(samaccountname=$person*))";
$justthese = array("ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail");
$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justthese);
$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($info); echo '<pre/>';
```

I've googled this to death, read the PHP documentation about arrays, and read various similar posts here, but nothing seems to work for me.

I need to end up with:

```
 echo $email;
```

and get back:

```
 john.smith@mydomain.com
```

Comment: `$email = $info[0]['mail'][0];`

Comment: The dump tells you the EXACT array construct/path you need to follow to get to the email address...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is read what `print_r()` shows you.

```
(Array) [0](Array) > [mail](Array) > [0](string) => john.smith@mydomain.com

$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
$email = $info[0]['mail'][0];
echo $email;
```

See the section **Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax** on these docs http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

Basic DUMP analysis 101:

Omitting the irrelevant parts of the dump:

```
 Array                                            <-- $array
[0] => Array                                      <-- [0]
        [mail] => Array                           <-- ['mail']
                [0] => john.smith@mydomain.com    <-- [0]
```

giving you

```
$array[0]['mail'][0];
```

Comment: Many thanks, much appreciated.  Sorry stack overflow doesn't allow me to mark both answers as correct!  :)